# random numbers scaled into parametrized intervals

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, random-numbers, robust-commands

MOTIVATION: To point shade a diagram. Points have random coordinates. They cluster around hidden user input coordinates more or less far out depending on those inputs.

> How would one use `\pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate ...}` (or different code if that is faster when for loop iterated) to construct a macro `\graf{b,x}` which returns a *random* real number z of *the same order of magnitude* (parametrized  b) as the control input a real number x?

So if 0 ≤ x < b^1, then 0 ≤ z ≤ b^1, and if b^1 ≤ x < b^2, then b^1 ≤ z ≤ b^2, ... Approximate is accurate enough.

The `\graf` hopefully can be defined such that `\graf{\B,{\X-\Y}}` will expand correctly, even when `\M{\graf{\B,{\X-\Y}}}` for some other macro `\M`, without blocking the compile or having to compile twice.

Comment: The magnitude order is (more or less, but it's not really important as you need random numbers) `n=floor(log x/log b)`. Then you can scale a random number `r` in `[0,1)` to fall in `[b^n,b^{n+1})`

Comment: do you really need those quantifiers ? This is floating point arithmetic. That distinction is not relevant. Plus not everybody understands the math notation on this site.

Comment: -egreg: Yes, some flooring is needed. I have no idea which packages to use to code this to work best when put in tikz later. -percusse: Yes, the quantifiers aren't important. Rewrote the problem statement a bit. Is this better? Robustness would be important (many of these random iterative pulls run out of memory or do not expand as expected).

Comment: do you mean normal (i.e. Gaussian) or uniform distribution ? it is not clear.

Comment: is it "`if 0 ≤ x < b^1`" or "`if 1≤ x< b^1`" ?

Comment: Gaussian is nice if possible; it is 0 for the second one, for both x and z. I would like fractional random z to be possible.

Comment: the issue with Gaussian is that it is not obvious what you mean by it as the support of this law is all of real line. Then there is an issue with your requirements is you say `if 0 ≤ x < b^1` on one hand but `if b^1 ≤ x < b^2 etc..` on the other hand. It doesn't look coherent.

Comment: If it was to be normally distributed, ideally, if say 10 ≤ x < 100, then we discard all normally distributed pulls z that turn out to be less than 10 or more than 100 until we get one that is 10 or more or 100 or less. We are intentionally (x) biasing our results while keeping limited randomness otherwise the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you need, but I compute the order of the number as the floor of its logarithm in base `b`, then generate a random number between 0 and 1 and rescale with an affine transformation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\graf}[2]{%
  \pgfmathparse{floor(ln(#2)/ln(#1))}%
  \pgfmathparse{#1^\pgfmathresult*(1+#1*rnd)}%
}

\newcommand{\showgraf}[2]{% to show
  \graf{#1}{#2}\pgfmathresult\par
}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily

\showgraf{3}{23.3}
\showgraf{10}{23.3}
\showgraf{10}{323.3}
\showgraf{10}{2333.3}
\showgraf{1.2}{1}
\showgraf{1.2}{10}
\showgraf{1.2}{100}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a fully expandable version, which should be usable also in coordinate computations. It doesn't work with XeTeX, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{luatex85} % if using LuaTeX

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\graf}{mm}
 {
  \guido_graf:fnn { \pdfuniformdeviate 1000000 } { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \guido_graf:nnn
 {
  \fp_eval:n
   {
    (#2**(floor(ln(#3)/ln(#2))))*(1+#2*(#1/1000000))
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \guido_graf:nnn { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ttfamily

\graf{3}{23.3}\par
\graf{10}{23.3}\par
\graf{10}{323.3}\par
\graf{10}{2333.3}\par
\graf{1.2}{1}\par
\graf{1.2}{10}\par
\graf{1.2}{100}\par

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works good by itself, but I am getting `incomplete iffalse; all text was ignored ...` error when trying various way to stick `{\graf{b}{x}}` into say `\draw (0,0) circle (n and m)` in place of the `n` and `m` or when I try to do `\showg{10}{100-{\graf{10}{5-4}}}`; but say `\showg{10}{5-4}` works. I think there is something I need to do to change the type of the output, so that it works in arithmetic or inside other macros. Or it needs order protection somewhere.

Comment: @GuidoJorg It is not expandable, like all `\pgfmath...` macros. You do `\graf{b}{x}` and the result is stored in `\pgfmathresult`.

Comment: I made another macro `\newcommand{\rrdd}[2]{\pgfmathparse{\graf{#1}{#2}\pgfmathresult}}` and this also does not allow me do say `\showgraf{10}{100-{\rrdd{10}{5}}}`. Or to use the random numbers inside other macros. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @GuidoJorg Everything. `;-)`. Try `\graf{10}{5-4}\graf{10}{100-\pgfmathresult}`. Now `\pgfmathresult` will store the new value.

Comment: Yes, I see, `\graf{10}{5}\graf{10}{100-\pgfmathresult}\pgfmathresult` works. Pgf is stacking. That leaves basically one question. `\graf{10}{5}\draw (0,0) circle ({\pgfmathresult} and {5+\graf{3}{10}\pgfmathresult});` sort of thing is not valid. What is my mistake here?

Comment: @GuidoJorg You cannot directly use `\graf` in a coordinate.

Comment: @GuidoJorg I added a fully expandable version

Comment: Works perfectly :-)